# how to make a value in XSL document to string and how to remove <dot-filename>graphs/node</dot-filename> tag after parsing xsl file using saxon?

Tags: xml, xslt, graphviz, dot

this my xsl code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML" version="3.0">
    <xsl:import href="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dotml2dot.xsl"/><xsl:param name="quot" as="xs:string">"</xsl:param>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="dotml">
          <xsl:for-each select = "Import/Row">
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>   
                <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="label">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </node>  

                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
                <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="from">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="to">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url || $quot'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </edge>   
          
          </xsl:for-each>         
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$dotml/node()"/>
      
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've followed your suggestion by adding <xsl:param name="quot" as="xs:string">"</xsl:param> tag on line 3 in my xsl document above. I've put the tag on every value in my xsl document, to retrieve the value in my xsl document, so that the value becomes a string

and when I run the code an error occurs as below:

`C:\Users\rafif\Desktop\saxons>java -jar saxon-he-10.6.jar -xsl:role policy.xsl -s:role-policy.xml -o:policy.txt`                                                                                                    `Error in xsl:param/@as on line 3 column 113 of role-policy.xsl:`                                                                                                                                                      `XPST0081  Namespace prefix 'xs' has not been declared`                                                                                                                                                            `Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation`

the question is, where should I put the `<xsl:param name="quot" as="xs:string">"</xsl:param>` tag because I've tried to put the tag on line 3, an error occurs

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems the stylesheet you use doesn't create the format you want or your other program needs, so ditch that stylesheet and write your own or at least edit it to not create e.g. `<dot-filename>graphs/node</dot-filename>`, that is, remove the line having `&lt;dot-filename&gt;<xsl:value-of select="@file-name"/>&lt;/dot-filename&gt;` from that code.

You can do that easily for a local copy of the file and `<xsl:import href="dotml2dot.xml"/>` that local copy instead of pulling the file from the server.

As for the quotes, it seems you want to convert e.g. `<xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>` to e.g. `<xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url || $quot'/> after declaring e.g.` <xsl:param name="quot" as="xs:string">"</xsl:param>` as a global parameter.

Comment: where the position i type the global parameter: <xsl:param name="quot" as="xs:string">"</xsl:param> ?

Comment: could you give me example please?? about the global params

Comment: Anywhere in the XSLT document you wrote as a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet`, for instance `<xsl:import href="..."/><xsl:param name="quot" as="xs:string">"</xsl:param>`.

Comment: i've edit my question above, could you help me, you can see all of my xsl code, i've followed your suggest but still error, could you help me please.. thank you

Comment: I told you to ditch the import or to use a local copy where you remove the code you don't seem to want to be generated. Your current edit with `<xsl:import href="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML/dotml2dot.xsl"/>` suggests you are still using the original file from the server. And of course, if you use `as="xs:string"`, you also need `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` declared on the `xsl:stylesheet`, to make any minimal sense.

Comment: thankyou very much martin, the output I want is appropriate because of your suggestion, thank you martin, I'm sorry if I ask a lot

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct answer...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.martin-loetzsch.de/DOTML" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.0">
        <xsl:import href="dotml2dot.xsl"/>
        <xsl:param name="quot" as="xs:string">"</xsl:param>
        <xsl:output method="text"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="dotml">
              <xsl:for-each select = "Import/Row">
                <graph  file-name="graphs/nice_graph" rankdir="LR">
                    <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="label">
                            <xsl:value-of select='role'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </node>   
                    <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="label">
                            <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </node>   
                    <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="label">
                            <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </node>   
                    <node style="filled" fontsize="16">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="label">
                            <xsl:value-of select='items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </node>  
    
                    <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                        <xsl:attribute name="from">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="to">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pns"]/url || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </edge>   
                    <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                        <xsl:attribute name="from">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="to">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="pppk"]/url || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </edge>   
                    <edge fontname="Arial" fontsize="9" label="Permit">
                        <xsl:attribute name="from">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || role || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="to">
                            <xsl:value-of select='$quot || items/subMenu[@name="ppt"]/url || $quot'/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </edge>   
                </graph>
              </xsl:for-each>         
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$dotml/node()"/>
          
        </xsl:template>    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).